# undo object smoothing [remove subdivision surface]

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, texture-baking

While I was working in *Edit Mode*, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, which smoothed my object. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>, which unsmoothed my object, and I moved on. However, when I bake a texture, it appears in the smoothed manner, I have gone long distances after that.

Is there any way to undo that smooth?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! So you have still a subsurf modifier with 0 subdivision for the preview and (perhaps) 2 for the render? Baking consider the render settings, that's probably why you experience that behaviour.

Comment: It is because this shortcuts adds a subdivision modifier. Ctrl+0 keeps it but set it to 0 for the view only. But keep it to 2 for the rendering. Have a look to the modifier panel and remove the modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the shortcut to add a *Subdivision surface* object modifier. This modifier uses an algorithm to smooth your object at a certain number of specified levels. To remove the modifier, not just disable it go to the *Properties panel > Object modifiers tab (blue wrench)* and click the *X* to remove it.

*The subsurf modifier (image from the [Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Rking/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf)):*

[image]

Comment: @SundarBons Glad to help!